# Парсинг данных с betfair на python

Tags: python-3.x, парсер

Необходимо раз в сутки при запуске программы получать коэффициенты на лошадей с каждого из рынков Великобритании с сайта https://www.betfair.com/exchange/plus/horse-racing. Чтобы увидеть коэффициенты просто в браузере, авторизация не нужна.

Пробовал сделать это, используя requests и BeautifulSoup, но столкнулся с тем, что html этой страницы фактически не содержит этих данных, и они генерируются лишь после соответствующего нажатия на ссылку конкретного забега.

Нужная мне информация находится под тегом "ui-view", но до коэффициентов я могу добраться лишь через F12. Парсер на вышеуказанных библиотеках ничего не возвращает.

Через инспектор кода я выяснил, ответ на какой запрос содержит нужные мне данные. Открывая эти ссылки в отдельном окне, я могу без проблем распарсить их «на лету», либо распарсить сохранённый XML-файл.

Например, для первых трёх сегодняшних забегов на ипподроме Winsor (15.04) ссылки на то место, куда уходят запросы при нажатии кнопки забега, будут выглядеть так:
https://www.betfair.com/www/sports/exchange/readonly/v1/bymarket?_ak=nzIFcwyWhrlwYMrh&currencyCode=EUR&locale=ru&marketIds=1.157583827&rollupLimit=10&rollupModel=STAKE&types=MARKET_STATE,MARKET_RATES,MARKET_DESCRIPTION,EVENT,RUNNER_DESCRIPTION,RUNNER_STATE,RUNNER_EXCHANGE_PRICES_BEST,RUNNER_METADATA,MARKET_LICENCE

https://www.betfair.com/www/sports/exchange/readonly/v1/bymarket?_ak=nzIFcwyWhrlwYMrh&currencyCode=EUR&locale=ru&marketIds=1.157583832&rollupLimit=10&rollupModel=STAKE&types=MARKET_STATE,MARKET_RATES,MARKET_DESCRIPTION,EVENT,RUNNER_DESCRIPTION,RUNNER_STATE,RUNNER_EXCHANGE_PRICES_BEST,RUNNER_METADATA,MARKET_LICENCE

https://www.betfair.com/www/sports/exchange/readonly/v1/bymarket?_ak=nzIFcwyWhrlwYMrh&currencyCode=EUR&locale=ru&marketIds=1.157583837&rollupLimit=10&rollupModel=STAKE&types=MARKET_STATE,MARKET_RATES,MARKET_DESCRIPTION,EVENT,RUNNER_DESCRIPTION,RUNNER_STATE,RUNNER_EXCHANGE_PRICES_BEST,RUNNER_METADATA,MARKET_LICENCE
Как видно, разница в этих ссылках только в элементе «marketIds». Где можно автоматически получить перечень этих элементов для всех забегов я так и не смог найти.

Собственно, вопрос: как можно средствами python получать подобные ссылки для дальнейшего их парсинга?

Comment: Обновил ссылки до актуальных на сегодня, 15.04.19

Comment: 1) Посмотрите в инспекторе браузера какой запрос выполняется при клике на ту кнопку 2) либо используйте, например, selenium, и им тыкайте на кнопку

Comment: gil9red, спасибо за ответ. По первому пункту, ссылки на запросы из инспектора браузера я отметил в тексте (на запросе в инспекторе я нажимал open in new tab и копировал ссылку из появившегося окна). Просто я не знаю, как их получить автоматически средствами python.

Comment: Если я правильно вас понял, то после загрузки ссылки по кнопке, происходит редирект и первоначальный адрес меняется. Тогда, если вы работаете через requests, то после загрузки (rs = requests.get / requests.post) проверьте текущий адрес через `rs.url`

Comment: gil9red, по первоначальной ссылке: https://www.betfair.com/exchange/plus/horse-racing находятся кнопки с каждым  из забегов на текущий день. При нажатии на кнопку к адресу страницы добавляется идентификатор забега, имеющий вид: /market/1.157582561 
Но при инспектировании кнопки через инспектор кода делается запрос xhr, который, при открытии его во вкладке браузера, даёт ссылку, подобную той, что в вопросе (со своим идентификатором забега, который совпадает с указанным выше). Ответ, по-сути, является xml-документом.